# JS integrer division

Tags: javascript, v8

Since in Javascript all the numbers are `double precision float` is just a matter of he memory representation or numerical operation are as well all the same?

E.g. regarding computation complexity

```
15 / 3
14 / 3
```

would these operation cost the same computational resources or would v8 optimize integer devision case?

Comment: Unless your code does millions of numeric operations per second, I advise to focus your optimization effort on areas where it can bring real value, like network, database and disk access, nested loops, calling a function multiple times etc.

Comment: discussion here: [Is there some way to do genuine integer arithmetic in JS?](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/8ci64t/is_there_some_way_to_do_genuine_integer/) also see [asmjs](http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/)

Answer (score 1):

(V8 developer here.)

Short answer: **It's complicated!** And (as axiac points out) also not worth worrying about.

Long answer:
First off, when you have a division of number literals like `15 / 3` in your source, then V8 will constant-fold that at parsing time, so the division will only be performed once, and it doesn't really matter whether it's optimized in any way or not. For example, if you write `function f() { return 15/3; }`, then that will get compiled to `function f() { return 5; }`.

The next important observation is that the only way to tell whether a division will have an integer result is to actually perform the division and look at the result. Concretely, if an engine wanted to have something like:

```
function implementation_of_/_operator(x, y) {
  if (division_result_will_be_integer(x, y)) {
    return integer_division(x, y);
  else {
    return floating_point_division(x, y);
  }
}
```

then it would have to implement `division_result_will_be_integer` somehow, for which there are two options:

```
function division_result_will_be_integer(x, y) {
  if (!is_integer(x) || !is_integer(y)) return false;
  return is_integer(floating_point_division(x, y));
}
// or:
function division_result_will_be_integer(x, y) {
  if (!is_integer(x) || !is_integer(y)) return false;
  (quotient, remainder) = integer_division_with_remainder(x, y);
  return remainder == 0;
}
```

Clearly, performing a division just to decide which additional division to perform afterwards is silly, and it would be faster to skip that whole dance and just always do a floating-point division directly.

The third relevant point is that the hardware instruction for integer division can be quite slow. In particular, for large dividends and small divisors, it tends to be slower than floating-point division instructions. So what your question assumes to be an "optimization" may well reduce performance in practice.

Regardless of integer or floating-point domain, divisions are always fairly expensive operations. In case both operands are integers, divisions can be [replaced by multiplications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Division_by_a_constant) with the "multiplicative inverse" of the divisor. Finding this multiplicative inverse again involves a division though, so this technique only improves performance if you expect to perform many divisions with the same divisor -- such as when the divisor is a constant, e.g. `f(x) { return x / 3; }`. Also, operating on integers means that only integer results can be represented; if someone called `f(14)` in this example, then the multiplication-by-inverse technique would produce an incorrect result.
V8 uses this approach in optimized code if (1) the divisor is a constant and (2) at the time of optimizing the given function, all results it's previously seen produced at this particular division were integers. Such optimized code must then still contain a check to verify that all future results are also integers, i.e. it must check that `division_result * dividend === divisor`, and otherwise bail out to a floating-point division.

Lastly, there's the somewhat special handling of asm.js-style code. If you write `f(x, y) { return ((x | 0) / (y | 0) | 0); }`, then V8 will use an integer division instruction in that function. Obviously, the `|0` operations mean that this function truncates both inputs and its result to 32-bit integers, which may or may not be acceptable for your use cases. Whether this will be faster or slower than a plain simple worry-free `function f(x, y) { return x / y; }` also depends on your use cases.